# Database Critique - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Would anybody be able to recommend any free or paid for services out there to assess and critique a database produced in MS Access?

Any help or advice appreciated, cheers
Noel

Comment: Why do you need this service? If you need help with the development then ask specific questions here, if you are worried that you might not have used best practice then ask specific questions with example code here and read about best practice on the web. I really doubt that you are going to find any kind of Access review service.

Comment: though I agree with Lazarus - I would recommend the services of SSW.COM.AU they used to be Access masters

Comment: @Lazarus, it was really your second point about using best practices that would be my main concern. I imagine that the only way that this possible would be to contact local/national MS specialists. @preet sangha cheers for the recomendation

Comment: I don't understand the question, because I don't know why you'd be in this position to wonder if your app was any good. You either know it is or you don't! You either know you need to learn more or you don't! Find a professional whose expertise you trust and hire them, if you really need to. In the meantime, try this: http://www.team-moeller.de/en/?Add-Ins:TM_VBA-Inspector . I don't necessarily agree that everything it flags is a problem, but it will give you plenty of things that it flags that you can then use as a project to investigate and learn about.

Comment: Hi David, perhaps its a confidence/experience thing. After creating an app that appears to work fine, there could still be things that are overlooked that may be more obvious to an experienced developer. Or perhaps I'm just being over cautious/ lacking confidence. Cheers for the pointer towards the VBA inspector.

Comment: You know that lacking confidence is a sign of competence. They recently did studies and found that the higher the level of self-doubt, the higher the level of accomplishment, and the higher the level of confidence, the lower the level of confidence.

Comment: @David: How confident were they in their conclusions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft occasionally identifies specific talented individuals as "MVPs". These people are experts with their craft and a few probably offer paid consulting.  Here's a list of the officially recognized Access MVPs.

https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/communities/mvp.aspx?product=1&competency=Access

However, as the others said, you'd be better off just posting your questions here.

Comment: And a few of us even hang out on StackOverlow.

Comment: Just because you're an MVP doesn't mean you have broad expertise and experience in Access, only enough to get the designation. Likewise, there are plenty of people who've never been MVPs who know as much or more than most MVPs.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of people who hang out here are in the business of fixing other people's databases (I know I am).  But I doubt anyone wants to use StackOverflow to directly solicit business.

What you want is an experienced database programmer or consultant.  Assuming your database is not extremely complex and assuming that you're asking them to review only the database structure itself and not any associated programming, a day of their time should suffice to review and report on your project.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are looking for critique..could you be more specific about what you feel may be lacking, flawed or limited in your Access app?..entity-relationships/table design flaws?.. macros?.. SQL statements?..etc?